# android volley OnTimeout mehod

Tags: android, android-volley

How to handle the timeout event in volley, e.g., give a hint for user? I cannot find any useful stuff after googling.

Should I write the logic in `Response.ErrorListener()` when creating a request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Exception called TimeoutError defined in Volley , You can make use of that. adding an example below

```
Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
        if (volleyError.networkResponse == null) {
            if (volleyError.getClass().equals(TimeoutError.class)) {
                // Show timeout error message
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                        "Oops. Timeout error!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Also please see this [link](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.android.volley.TimeoutError)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `if (volleyError.getClass().equals(TimeoutError.class))` I would suggest to use `if (volleyError instanceof TimeoutError)`. Because `volleyError.getClass()` can throw **NullPointerException**. And obviously it will decrease your line of codes as well.

```
Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
        if (volleyError instanceof TimeoutError) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Oops. Timeout error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }
});
```

Comment: instanceof tests whether the object reference on the left-hand side (LHS) is an instance of the type on the right-hand side (RHS) or some subtype. and getClass() checks if the types are identical. so here getClass() would be appropriate.